# dhclient prints strange error

Tags: linux-mint, dhclient

Though it looks like it does its job it prints following annoying output

```
# dhclient -r eth0
reload: Unknown instance: 
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "reload" failed.
# dhclient eth0
reload: Unknown instance: 
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "reload" failed.
```

which I would like to fix.

Linux Mint 17 Qiana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page for `dhclient` has this to say about the `-r` flag

> **-r** Release the current lease and  stop  the  running  DHCP  client  as  previously recorded  in  the PID file.  When shutdown via this method `dhclient-script` will be executed [...]

The interesting part here is the reference to `dhclient-script`. It turns out that this is a shell script (`locate dhclient-script | xargs -n1 type -p`). Perusing this script shows that it in turn references any files in the directory `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d`. One of the files there is called `samba`, which is also a shell script. Near the end of this script are these lines

```
# reload the samba server
# We don't necessarily have the samba package installed. #414841
[ -x /etc/init.d/smbd ] && /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d smbd reload
```

This checks that `/etc/init.d/smbd` is executable, and if so calls it with the `reload` parameter.

One simple solution is to remove execute permission from this file (`chmod a-x /etc/init.d/smbd`), but any update to the Samba package will probably overwrite that change. A better solution may be to remove the Samba packages (the reload is probably failing because Samba isn't configured, so isn't running).

Answer (score 2):

I had a related error which disallowed me from getting a new dhcp lease (and therefor surf around the 'net);

> Job for smbd.service invalid.
>
> invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "reload" failed.

Running dhclient -r in this case resulted in a repeat of that error message.

Running:

> service smbd start

.. and following that up with an ifdown/ifup resolved my lease issue and surfing has since been resumed.  Perhaps running 'service smbd status' might give additional workable information.

(I'm aware the question is considered closed because it's been answered, just adding this in case it's helpful to others who come across this message while looking for the error I ran into, exactly as I did. :) )

Comment: StackExchange is a little different to what you may be used to. We don't close questions when they've been answered, and new relevant answers are always welcomed.

Comment: Good to know.  Thank you for the info, roaima!

Answer (score -1):

Updating `samba` solved this for me:

```
apt-get upgrade samba
```